# Adding array to Json Object outputs array of arrays instead of one array of values (using Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

When adding an array to a json object from two separate select lists i get an array of arrays instead of one array with all the values inside. I'll explain further below:

I get my expected output when I've selected **two** items from **one** select list. When that's the case, this code runs:

```
var jsonObject = {};
jsonObject["someKey"] = $("#selectList1").val();
console.log(jsonObject);
```

console:

```
▼ Object {someKey: Array[2]}
    ▼ someKey: Array[2]
        0: "value1"
        1: "value2"
        length: 2
      ► __proto__:Array[0]
    ► __proto__: Object
```

So the above is correct. But when I select **one** item from **two** separate lists each, this code runs:

```
var jsonObject = {};
jsonObject["keys"] = new Array($("#selectList1").val(), $("#selectList2").val());

console.log(jsonObject);
```

console:

```
▼ Object {someKey: Array[2]}
    ▼ someKey: Array[2]
     ▼ 0: Array[1]
         0: "value1"
         length: 1
       ►__proto__: Array[0]
     ▼ 1: Array[1]
         0: "value2"
         length: 1
       ►__proto__: Array[0]
       length: 2
     ► __proto__:Array[0]
    ► __proto__: Object
```

The above is not my desired output. I've also ran this code, which outputs the same undesired output:

```
var keys = [];
keys.push($("#selectList1").val());
keys.push($("#selectList2").val());

jsonObject["keys"] = keys;
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `new Array($("#selectList1").val()[0], $("#selectList2").val()[0])`

Comment: Have a look at [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: Why are you using multi-select if you only want to select one item from the list?

Comment: @Barmar The user has to select two items. either two from the same list, or one from either of the two lists.

Comment: Seems like a confusing UI. If he selects one from list 1 and two from list 2, it will just ignore the second from list 2.

Comment: @Barmar an error message is displayed.

Comment: i know it sounds weird, but this is very deliberate and specific to our needs.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue you need to be careful with, is in cases where the query for selected values returns empty, since the array operator (`[]`) or `concat` will fail:

```
// Select first array of selected values.
// It can be null so we make it by default an empty array.
var selected = ($("#select-1").val() || [])
  // Then concatenate with second array of values
  .concat($("#select-2").val());
```

Another elegant way to achieve this, could be querying the selects first, then iterating them for values:

```
var selected = $("#select-1,#select-2").map(function (i, select) {
    return $(select).val();
  }).toArray();
```

The later is more readable and you avoid the `maybeNotAnArray || []` hack.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @depperm for your suggestion:

```
new Array($("#selectList1").val()[0], $("#selectList2").val()[0])
```

it worked..

Comment: You don't need `new Array()`, just write an array literal `[$("#selectList1").val()[0], $("#selectList2").val()[0]]`